# Build constraints exclude all Go protobuffer generated files

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have updated go from v1.14 to 1.16 and now my generated go proto rise build errors.

My project structure:

```
project_folder
|-- proto_folder
    |--data.proto
    |--data.pb.go
|--client
    |--client.go
|--main.go
```

When I try to import `proto_folder` in `client/client.go`:

```
import(
   pb "project_folder/proto_folder"
   "net/http"
   "net/url"
)

func SendData(data *DataContainer) {
    
    requestAddr := "http://localhost:8080/data"
    out, err := proto.Marshal(data)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", requestAddr, bytes.NewBuffer(out))
    //exec request with http client
    .....
}
```

I get the error from the IDE (Goland):

`Build constraints exclude all Go files in '/usr/local/go/src/project_folder/proto_folder'`

When I try to build with `go build` I get this error:

```
package project_folder
    imports project_folder/client
    imports project_folder/proto_folder: no Go files in /usr/local/go/src/project_folder/proto_folder
```

Comment: how are you importing this, how is your module structured, and what are the build constraints?

Comment: I didn't change anything of the structure after update to go 1.16

Comment: I didn't ask if you changed anything; what we need is all the missing information to construct a [mre].

Comment: I have update the question. Let me know if you need others details

Comment: You are importing `"project_folder/proto_folder"`, but that is not a valid import path. It's missing the module name to locate the package. How is your module defined in `go.mod`?

Comment: I have found the problem. Check on release of [golang 1.16](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes) there are changes about GOPATH mode. The go folder move from my home ( where I had set the GOPATH) to `/usr/local`. When I build the application, the compiler use `/usr/loca/go` as GOPATH instead of go folder im my home ( set in GOPATH env variable). I am generating the proto inside my GOPATH folder so the compiler can't see it.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct, as `/usr/local/go` is the generally the default GOROOT, but I'm glad you got it working. You should however be using go modules, as GOPATH builds are deprecated and are not going to work with an increasing number of dependencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230508/discussion-between-stefano-castoldi-and-jimb).